# How does one use shift sequences to output a character from another character set

Tags: c, character-encoding, internationalization, escaping, shift-jis

Reading about how to use shift sequences to print characters from other character sets I've arrived at the following code (of which I'm sure the escape sequence is incorrect, however I do not know why):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\x1B\x28\x49\x0E\xB3"); /* Should print: ｳ */
    return 0;
}
```

This however is not working for me as it outputs a "?" in the terminal rather than the character "ｳ".  My font does indeed have support for the character.  If someone could explain what I'm doing incorrectly and how I would go about correcting this(still using shift sequences), that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you print `ｳ` any other way to your terminal? (`terminfo` may or may not tell you whether your terminal supports this -- I cannot find the precise keywords to look for.)

Comment: yes I can, when I run cat main.c, (which has `ｳ` in the comment, it is visible as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using ISO-2022-JP-3. Hence you need to write your program as follows:

```
int main ()
{
    // switch to JIS X 0201-1976 Kana set (1 byte per character)
    printf ("\x1B(I");

    printf ("\x33"); /* ｳ */

    // mandatory switch back to ASCII before end of line
    printf ("\x1B(B");

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note however that it is unlikely to be the character set expected by the terminal (on linux, this is most likely UTF-8). You can use iconv to perform the conversion:

```
$ ./main | iconv -f ISO-2022-JP-3
```

Alternatively you can use iconv(3) to perform the conversion inside your program.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for (except I had to remove that last hyphen to make it work)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do `echo 'ｳ' >/tmp/x && od -x /tmp/x` - do you see the same hex characters as you are using in the example above? I'm betting not, and I've based this answer on that bet.

Your `cat` works because `ｳ` is encoded in your source file as UTF-8.

You have your terminal set to UTF-8 (or more likely it's just defaulting to UTF-8) so UTF-8 works, but Shift-JIS does not.